# Restrict access to development server/website

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I've got both my test site and stable site on one AWS EC2 server. I've successfully set up ACL and some other stuff for other people to access to the test site files.

However, I do not want to expose the test site to the public (debugging mode is on). And most of us work remotely. means I can not set up Apache to restrict access by IP address.

So I was wondering If set up a VPN on the server would solve the problem, or are there more secure/easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something as simple as setting up a .htaccess file in the web directory root and give everyone the same username/password.

See this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html
And look for the Authentication Example.

Comment: Would it require entering username/password everytime I refresh the page?